# Android single Web View to open multiple pdf

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to display many PDF(around 50) in my android app. Now to display these how can I use single Activity to open all the PDF or I have to make 50 activity. Does making 50 activity to open 50 PDF will slow down app or increase size of the apk. I want to display PDFs in webview.

Comment: You don't need to create 50 different activities. Instead, use the concept of `Fragments`. Check out http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html
If you are rendering it in WebView, you can do that in a single webview too

Comment: If you're looking at a webview based PDF Viewer, check this : https://github.com/BrunoAndroidDev/PDFViewer